# What closed a foundation modal in closed event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, zurb-foundation, zurb-foundation-5

Using Foundation 5 modal dialogs. Is there a way to pass what fired the close event.  Like a button or a link?  Something like this.  I tried using the data attribute but that doesn't seem to work.

```
$('#cancelbutton').on('click',function() { 
     $('#mymodal').foundation('reveal','closed',{data:'cancelbutton'});
});
$(document).on('closed.fndtn.reveal', '[data-reveal]', function (e) {
     var closer = e.data;
});
```

Comment: have you tried e.target.id?

Comment: e.target is the modal box in the closed event.

Comment: If you can reproduce it in a fiddle, I would be more than happy to help

Answer (score 0):

I think e.target should work for the click event, try:

```
  $(document)
    .on('click.fndtn.reveal', '.reveal-modal-bg, .close-reveal-modal, a, button', function (e) {
     e.preventDefault();

     console.log(e.target);

    });
```

Notice that `e.target` is a DOM Element (you can convert it to a jQuery object by using `$(e.target)`)